# What is MonetaryAmount.plus() used for? Which Kotlin operator to map it to?

Tags: java, kotlin, java-money

I'm using JSR 354 a.k.a [`JavaMoney`](https://javamoney.github.io/ri.html), and I don't understand what `MonetaryAmount.plus()` is supposed to do?

For all implementations of `MonetaryAmount` I found, it simply returns `this`. The documentation is not helpful to me:

```
Returns a {@code MonetaryAmount} whose value is <code>+this</code>, with rounding according to
the context settings.
```

This is a bit unfortunate when using Kotlin, which has operator overloading for the function `plus` which maps the operator `+` onto this function, where as it should map onto `add` in this case.

This can be fixed:

```
    operator fun MonetaryAmount.plus(other: MonetaryAmount) = this.add(other)
```

But I'm not sure onto what operator I should map the `plus()` function to? `UnaryPlus`?

Comment: Looks like unary plus, yes. It's useless by default but can be useful when overloaded for a custom type. In Kotlin it's called [`unaryPlus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/unary-plus.html).